# Cannot run TexLive Manager for TeXLive 2008

Tags: installing, texlive, windows

I have simultaneous implementations of TL 2008, TL 2010 and TL 2011 on my Windows XP machine. However after installing TL 2011, I find that I cannot run the TeXLive Manager for 2008. The path for the TL 2008 manager is still correct:

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\texlive\2008\bin\win32\tlmgr.bat" gui
```

A dos window pops up and gives me this message:

```
Loading local TeX Live Database
This may take some time, please wait!
TeXLive::TLUtils::setup_programs (w32) failed at C:/texlive/2011/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2192.
C:\texlive\2011\tlpkg\installer\wget\wget.exe --version failed (status 256):
Output is:
wget: WGETRC points to C:/texlive/2011/tlpkg/installer/wgetrc, which doesn't exist.

Couldn't set up the necessary programs.
Installation of packages is not supported.
Please report to texlive@tug.org.
Continuing anyway ...
Completed.
```

Any suggestions as to how to correct this behaviour?

Updated: Contents of tlmgr.bat

```
@echo off
rem tl-w32-starter.bat
rem universal script starter, batch file part
rem this program calls the tl-w32-wrapper.texlua
setlocal
set ownpath=%~dp0%
texlua "%ownpath%tl-w32-wrapper.texlua" "%~dpn0" %*
endlocal
```

Comment: What does `tlmgr.bat` look like? It seems to be pointing to your `/texlive/2011` folder rather than `/texlive/2008`.

Comment: @Werner Thanks. I've included its contents in the post.

Comment: Does it fix things if you add the absolute path to `texlua`? That is, use `C:\Program Files\texlive\2008\bin\win32\texlua` instead of just `texlua`.

Comment: @Werner. Yes perfect! it works. Please convert your comment into an answer here and I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are running multiple versions of TeXLive, executables from the most recent installed version will be used as default. Providing an absolute path to the specific TeX Live distribution should fix your problem. That is, direct `texlua` to actually use

```
C:\Program Files\texlive\2008\bin\win32\texlua
```

in your `tlmgr.bat` for TeX Live 2008.

Answer (score 2):

It should be quite obvious from the error message that your system is set up to use TL'11 and not TL'08.  The suggestion given in another answer to "fix" `tlmgr.bat` by using the absolute paths to `texlua` does not really solve the problem -- `tlmgr` may still need some other utilities (e.g., `kpsewhich`) and will still end up using the wrong one.  It pains me to see such advice as an accepted answer.  Altering the original files is never a good idea and should not be encouraged except as the last resort.

The correct solution is to set up the `PATH` variable, so that the right TL utilities are found.  You can do that either system-wide, or per command interpreter (`cmd.exe`) session, or with some wrappers, or whatever suits you best.  The assumption is that users wishing to manage multiple versions of TL already know their platform well enough to properly switch between different TL versions.